# Can I wait for a process to complete when consuming RabbitMQ messages with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, es6-promise

I'm pretty new to Node.js and ES6, and this is just confusing me a little bit. I am trying to leave a process running, consuming messages from a RabbitMQ queue. It needs to be able to process the message (which takes about 30-60 seconds) before it grabs the next message. Currently, the code I have, it grabs all messages it can and then tries to fork the processes. When there are 3-5 messages in the queue, this is fine, but for 20, 50 or 100 messages, this causes the server to run out of memory.

I have tried making the `.consume()` callback function async and adding `await` to the message processing function. I have tried wrapping an `await new Promise` within the `.consume()` callback around `processMessage`. I have tried adding `await` to the line that calls `channel.consume`. Nothing changes the behavior.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const amqp = require('amqplib');

const consumeFromQueue = async (queue, isNoAck = false, durable = false, prefetch = null) => {
    const conn_str = "amqp://" + process.env.RABBITMQ_USERNAME + ":" + process.env.RABBITMQ_PASSWORD + "@" + process.env.RABBITMQ_HOST + "/development?heartbeat=60"
    const cluster = await amqp.connect(conn_str);
    const channel = await cluster.createChannel();
    await channel.assertQueue(queue,  { durable: durable, autoDelete: true });
    if (prefetch) {
        channel.prefetch(prefetch);
    }
    console.log(` [x] Waiting for messages in ${queue}. To exit press CTRL+C`)

    try {
        channel.consume(queue, message => {
            if (message !== null) {
                console.log(' [x] Received', message.content.toString());
                processMessage(message.content.toString());
                channel.ack(message);
                return null;
            } else {
                console.log(error, 'Queue is empty!')
                channel.reject(message);
            }
        }, {noAck: isNoAck});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error, 'Failed to consume messages from Queue!')
        cluster.close(); 
    }
}

exports.consumeFromQueue = consumeFromQueue;
```

As a sidenote, if I create an array of strings and loop through the strings, when I add await to the `processMessage` line, it waits to execute process (30-60 seconds) before processing the next string.

```
(async () => {
    for (let i=0; i<urls.length; i++) {
        await processMessage(urls[i]);
    }
})();
```

So I basically need something that functions like this, but with listening to the queue in RabbitMQ.

Comment: What value of `prefetch` do you pass into your `consumeFromQueue` function?

Comment: @shkaper Just null for now.

Comment: Prefetch count is what limits the number of messages that can be processed at a time by a consumer. Try limiting it to 3-5.

Comment: If I set prefetch, it doesn't seem that I can get any more messages until I restart my node script. Also, if I process 5 messages at once, I am unable to verify whether any are duplicates, and so could run into issues there. I am just wondering if there is anyway to wait for the process to finish before it gets a new message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to limit the number of messages being processed by a consumer at any given time, use [channel.prefetch()](https://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_prefetch):

> The count given is the maximum number of messages sent over the
>   channel that can be awaiting acknowledgement; once there are count
>   messages outstanding, the server will not send more messages on this
>   channel until one or more have been acknowledged.

That is, if you only want to be able process a single message at a time before moving on to the next, set `channel.prefetch(1)`

Comment: Hmm, this is definitely what I want. I just tested it now. It seems to still just be getting any new messages right away. I start the node script, and I send it 3 messages, and it processes all 3 instantly, without waiting for the message to finish processing, even though `channel.prefetch(1)` is now explicitly called.

Comment: @KenyonRosewall What's the `processMessage`? Could it be an asynchronous function by any chance?

Comment: If it is, and you don't wait for its execution, the message gets acked right away and the broker sends another immediately.

Comment: It uses pupeteer, which is asynchronous with a bunch of awaits and callbacks in there. I'm trying to figure out how to setup the rabbitmq layer to `await` the asynchronous process.

Comment: Yeah, how do I wait for the async process before acking the message?

Comment: You can make the consumer async, i.e. `channel.consume(queue, async (message) => { ...`, then `await processMessage(...); channel.ack(message)`. Or simply use the promise chain: `processMessage(...).then(() => { channel.ack(message) })`

Comment: Great, that was it. I just hadn't done the async callback AND prefetch(1) together. Now it is working as I want it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

moving on to the next, set channel.prefetch(1)

```
channel.prefetch(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs a complete answer:

You need to mix channel.prefetch(1), and { noAck: false } to consume one to one messages:

Simple Example:

```
const connection = await amqp.connect('amqp://localhost')    
const channel = await connection.createChannel()

await channel.assertQueue(queue, { durable: false })

// Set the number of messages to consume:
channel.prefetch(1)

await channel.consume(
      'QUEUE_NAME',
      async message => {
         if (message) {
            // YOUR ASYNC/AWAIT CODE

            // And then, ack the message manually:
            channel.ack(message)
         }
      },

      { noAck: false } // Set noAck to false to manually acknowledge messages
)
```

This is the way to consume a message at a time.